# Is there a method to simplify RegionIntersection between 2 spheres?

Tags: regions, intersection

I use RegionIntersection to find the circle between 2 spheres, but Mathematica returns :

```
RegionIntersection[
Sphere[Point[{-(1/4) Sqrt[3 + 6/Sqrt[5]], -(Sqrt[3]/4), Sqrt[
   3/4 + 3/(2 Sqrt[5])]}], 0.3], 
Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/4 (Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[15])]]
```

and not Cirlce[...] .
And if it is not possible is there a way to display this intersection in a Graphics3D , Mathematica says "RegionIntersection is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive."
Thank you.

Comment: "not `Circle[...]`" - because `Circle[]` as it is currently defined in *Mathematica* cannot be used to represent an object living in three dimensions. If you want to see it, look at `DiscretizeRegion[]`.

Answer (score 8):

Do not use `Graphics3D` with [regions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation.html). You cannot get `Circle` as simplified version, as it is 2D primitive in Wolfram Language (read docs on it), and you got 3D space. But the long expression you get after `RegionIntersection` is a 2D circle embedded in 3D:

```
Region[reg=RegionIntersection[
    Sphere[{-(1/4) Sqrt[3+6/Sqrt[5]],-(Sqrt[3]/4),Sqrt[3/4+3/(2 Sqrt[5])]},.3],
    Sphere[{0,0,0},1/4 (Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[15])]],
Boxed->True,Axes->True,SphericalRegion->True]
```

[image]

You can even compute its measure, which is 1D:

```
In[]:= RegionMeasure[reg]
Out[]= 1.87412

In[]:= ArcLength[reg]
Out[]= 1.87412
```

Comment: Thank you for your expanations. Do you know why the developpers of Mathematica allow to simplify and recognize some "special regions" as `RegionIntersection[]` between `InfiniteLine` and `Ball` ( see : [https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html] (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) ) and then displaying in Graphics3D ? it's extremely painful to have to use so many tools (Plot3D, Graphics3D, Region.... to visualize an object !

Answer (score 6):

If you'd also like a solution that gives you the position, radius and orientation of the circle you can use this:

```
getcircle[s1_, s2_] := 
 Block[{p1 = s1[[1]], p2 = s2[[1]], r1 = s1[[2]], r2 = s2[[2]],
   d = EuclideanDistance[s2[[1]], s1[[1]]],
   ori = Normalize[s2[[1]] - s1[[1]]]},
  {(*orientation*) ori,
   (*position*)p1 + ori*Sqrt[(d^2 + r1^2 - r2^2)^2/d^2]/2,
   (*radius*)Sqrt[4 d^2 r2^2 - (d^2 - r1^2 + r2^2)^2]/(2 d)
   }]

ms1 = Sphere[{-(1/4) Sqrt[3 + 6/Sqrt[5]], -(Sqrt[3]/4), Sqrt[3/4 + 3/(2 Sqrt[5])]}, 0.3];
ms2 = Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/4 (Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[15])];

{ori, pos, rad} = getcircle[ms2, ms1];
Graphics3D[{ Opacity[.25], ms1, ms2,
  Opacity[1], Arrow[{pos, pos + ori}],
  FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], 
  Cylinder[{pos, pos + 0.0001*ori}, rad]}]
```

[image: sphere sphere intersection]

Comment: Replacing `0.3` by `3/10` in the above, one obtains the exact solution `{-((Sqrt[3+6/Sqrt[5]] (339/400+3/(2 Sqrt[5])+1/16 (3+6/Sqrt[5])+1/16 (Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[15])^2))/(8 (15/16+3/(2 Sqrt[5])+1/16 (3+6/Sqrt[5])))),-((Sqrt[3] (339/400+3/(2 Sqrt[5])+1/16 (3+6/Sqrt[5])+1/16 (Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[15])^2))/(8 (15/16+3/(2 Sqrt[5])+1/16 (3+6/Sqrt[5])))),(Sqrt[3/4+3/(2 Sqrt[5])] (339/400+3/(2 Sqrt[5])+1/16 (3+6/Sqrt[5])+1/16 (Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[15])^2))/(2 (15/16+3/(2 Sqrt[5])+1/16 (3+6/Sqrt[5])))}`. for the center and the radius.

Comment: ^ which in turn simplifies to: `{-Sqrt[(3*(23545 + 9691*Sqrt[5]))/10]/200, -Sqrt[(3*(4163 + 273*Sqrt[5]))/2]/200, Sqrt[(3*(23545 + 9691*Sqrt[5]))/10]/100}`